# Dual of a Second Order Cone Program (SOCP)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I was reading on second order cone programs https://www.di.ens.fr/~aspremon/PDF/MVA/Duality.pdf page 33 and have trouble trying to derive its dual. While I am able to formulate the lagrangian easily, I do not understand how the following steps are carried out.

[image]
[image]

For the steps below, I perfectly understand that the minimum over x and t is only bounded if the expression in the green and blue boxes (excluding x and t) are zero. But what about the minimum over y ? Why is the infimum over y = 0 if the L2 norm of $v_i$ is less than $\lambda_i$ ?

[image]

Comment: Your question is closely related to the derivation of the convex conjugate of the 2-norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First assume that $\| \nu_i \|_2 \leq \lambda_i$. From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$
- \nu_i^T y_i \leq \| \nu_i \|_2 \| y_i \|_2 \leq \lambda_i \| y_i \|_2
$$
which implies that
$$
\lambda_i \| y_i \|_2 + \nu_i^T y_i \geq 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
\inf_{y_i} \,\lambda_i \| y_i \|_2 + \nu_i^T y_i = 0
$$
in this case.

Next assume that $\| \nu_i \|_2 > \lambda_i$.
Note that $\lambda_i$ is constrained to be nonnegative in the dual problem.
If we take $y_i = - s \nu_i$ for some $s > 0$, then 
\begin{align}
\lambda_i \| y_i \|_2 + \nu_i^T y_i &= \lambda_i s \| \nu_i \|_2 - s \| \nu_i \|_2^2 \\
&= s\| \nu_i \|_2 ( \underbrace{\lambda_i - \| \nu_i \|_2}_{< \,0 }),
\end{align}
which can be made as negative as we like by taking $s$ to be very large.
Thus in this case we have
$$
\inf_{y_i} \,\lambda_i \| y_i \|_2 + \nu_i^T y_i = -\infty.
$$

Comment: Thank you ! I did not learn about the cauchy-schwarz inequality so this is extra useful :)

Comment: Sure. A lot of computations similar to this one are done in the textbook [Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/), which might be worth checking out if you're not already reading it.

Comment: That is interesting. Based on the font I assumed the source of the question was exactly that book. As it turns out, the slides are copied from Question 5.43 of that book and its solution manual.